# Rails 4 - Uninstalled a gem but system is asking me to reinstall before I run server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm running rails 4.2.1 and have uninstalled a particular gem that was freezing my asset pipeline compiles thus not allowing me to update html, css, or javascript. Although I uninstalled the gem, when I attempt to run the server I get an error message stating `Could not find rails_serve_static_assets-0.0.4 in any of the sources` . I no longer want this gem anywhere in my stack. Any idea of how to get rid of that particular gem and all of its dependencies for good?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you remove it from your Gemfile too (and bundle install)? Worth also checking in Gemfile.lock to see if another gem you are using has it as a dependency.

Comment: great, needed to bundle install after doing the single gem uninstall. Thanks @shadwell

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that you have it in another gem.  Do these to start with a fresh bundle

```
bundle clean
bundle install
```